# How to use jQuery check upload image type and size (all file type HTML element)?

Tags: jquery, html, file, types, upload

I want to restrict upload file type and size to use all file elements on the same page (now I just succeeded in letting file type restrict function work).

My code like below:

```
//this part is working now
//restrict upload file type
$('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    switch (ext) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', false);
            break;
        default:
            alert('Only image file type please!!');
            this.value = '';
    }

//this part below i have no idea to make it work!!
// hope restrict file size in 1 MB
  if(this.size > 1024) {
         alert("Please check upload image not over 1MB");
        this.value = '';
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try out by myself (share to you !if you need !)

```
//restrict upload file type
$('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    switch (ext) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', false);
            break;
        default:
            alert('Only image file type please!!');
            this.value = '';
    }

// restrict file size in 1 MB
  if((this.files[0].size)/1024 > 1000) {
         alert("Please check upload image not over 1MB");
        this.value = '';
   }

});
```